# Special characters of google webfont in IE and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, character-encoding, explorer, google-webfonts

I'm trying to create page in Slovak language but I still have problem with Google Webfont Oswald in Firefox and IE. Problem is only with special characters of Slovak language. In Chrome it look right. http://pagina.chalupakoseckerovne.sk/
I tried change charset but nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select “Latin Extended” in the character set choice when selecting a Google font. Otherwise, only Latin-1 (“Western” Latin letters) are included.

It does not look right on Chrome either; it’s just that the fallback font used (the browser’s default sans-serif font) in your Chrome installation is so close to the Web font selected that you don’t easily notice a difference. (On my Chrome, the “Š” is absurdly smaller than other letters.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify encoding. You want

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
```

as the charset isn't specified, and that leads to your mojibake.